# Trouble Reinstalling Windows after Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7

I had problems with Windows, so about a year ago, we switched to Ubuntu.  Unfortunately the functionality was reduced, and so I want to go back to Windows, with all its problems.  I followed the instructions on other websites, and made the 4 restoration disc, and then put them in one at a time as instructed.

Then, I restarted and it says, "Restoration Incomplete".  And it doesn't do anything.  I'm using a Presario CQ56, and our restoration discs were made on a second computer, which was also a Presario CQ56.

I don't know how to get past this screen:
"Restoration Incomplete
The restoration did not complete.
Please select one of the following buttons:
Save Log  Details  Retry"

What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: I can assure you that functionality is not reduced!

Comment: This should be aksed on [su], it is not about ubuntu.